# two or more timer with different intervals with C#

Tags: c#, timer, intervals

I have to a d.b entry in which the intervals are given,

Suppose 1 timer tm_5 will check the entries after every 5 mins & the timer tm_10 will check

the entries after every 10 mins,

The problem is that it checks only the entries for tm_5 not for the tm_10.

I am using C#.net 2005 & MS sql server 2005.

Comment: can you provide code how are you doing this?

Comment: We won't be able to help you unless you provide a bit more information...

Comment: What kind of Timers, and how are they handled?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (add label1 and label2 to form named TimerTester).

```
public partial class TimerTester : Form
{
    public TimerTester()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Timer _t1;
    Timer _t2;
    int _it1 = 0, _it2 = 0;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _t1 = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };            
        _t1.Tick += new EventHandler(_t1_Tick);
        _t2 = new Timer() { Interval = 2000 };
        _t2.Tick += new EventHandler(_t2_Tick);
        _t1.Start(); _t2.Start();
    }
    void _t1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "t1: " + (_it1++).ToString();
    }
    void _t2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = "t2: " + (_it2++).ToString();
    }        
}
```

Also note that you should use Forms.Timer and not Threads.Timer (or use InvokeRequired and read & understand what it implicates).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the text of the label in the UI thread so this code will work. See Control.Invoke and Control.InvokeRequired for help.

Comment: I believe UI timer controls run on the UI thread.  Your concern is only valid for separate threads.  UI timers raise events on the UI thread.

Comment: @BlueMonkMN: I didn't see that he mentioned UI Timers is his question and also the code above does not mention that.

Comment: Thread-based timers require a parameter on the constructor and do not implement events, therefore it's safe to assume that the code listed above is using UI timers, which have a default constructor and raise the Tick event.